# Why is the pranava mantra "Om" pronounced as "Ogm" sometimes?

Tags: pranava

Is this just for phonetic reasons or is there a religious significance to inserting the "g" into "Om"?

for example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkZHov_RDVY

Does it happen (inserting a "g" before "m") with any other word?

Comment: I've never heard this. Do you have a video or something you could share?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkZHov_RDVY @cdr

Comment: tradition south only agum gumma is in bet AAkaaraa and maakaraa.. but no value i believe even i used to say by practice real meaning doesn't make sense or add up to any known definition of pronunication.

Comment: It is a tradition in the taittiriya shakha of south India to pronounce the anusvara (the M sound) as a "GM" sound whenever the anusvara comes before an s, sh, Sh, h, and I believe even r. For example, "OgM saytam", since "satyam" comes after the pranava, and satyam starts with letter S.